# Determine the file type downloaded by cURL

Tags: php

I have this code,

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/v1/items/id/preview",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer bearer-string",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    file_put_contents('file.jpeg', print_r($response, true));    
}
```

From that code I can tell that the response is jpeg that's why I assigned `file.jpeg` as filename.

Now my problem, what if the response is not jpeg?

I could not find any function from https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php that will dynamically determine what type of file is in response.

Any Idea about this.

Comment: Do you need to determine just if it's an jpeg or not or to find out which extension it is in case it's not jpeg?

Comment: I need to determine, a file whether a jpeg or just in case not jpeg

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl_getinfo to get content-type of what curl got

`$mime = curl_getinfo(response , CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);`
and then simply check if $mime equals to 'image/jpeg'